# JS: How to make logic (using loops) to insert data into this table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, yui

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9daLf2/). But it does not show anything. I couldn't figure out why.

---

The *structure* of a 2D array is like:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Name [1](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9daLf2/) => Age [2] => CGPA ) [1](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9daLf2/) => Array ( [0] => Alex [1](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9daLf2/) => 23 [2] => 2.5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9daLf2/) => 24 [2] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Mike [1](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9daLf2/) => 22 [2] => 3.9 ) )

We need to *load data from this array into a datatable* created in a *YUI module*.

So from the understanding I have got from my efforts, I think *we can not write our loops or code inside the YUI module block.* (Tell me if I am wrong) Otherwise it was easy, I could simply use for loops.

I still know I need to use for loops here. But I am at a loss at how to create the logic since I can not insert my code into the block of code which is the YUI module.
The code is given as follows.

**For ease of understanding,** I have inserted the data by referring to indices of the given array. It works perfectly fine, but we can not use indices like `0 1 2 3` etc. because we don't know what will be the length of the `2D array` and the 1D arrays it contains. **So can anybody give me a hand on this?**

```
M.mod_quiz.init_dataTable = function(Y, params) {

    var $rowArray= params.key1;

    alert($rowArray.length);

    /*for (i=0; i<$rowArray.length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<$rowArray[0].length; j++) {

        }
    }*/

    YUI().use("datatable-sort", function(Y) {
                    var cols = [
                        /*for (i=0; i<$rowArray.length; i++) {
                            {key:"Column "+i , label: $rowArray[0][i] , sortable=true}
                        }*/
                        {key:"Company", label:$rowArray[0][0], sortable:true},
                        {key:"Phone", label:$rowArray[0][1], sortable:true},
                        {key:"Contact", label:$rowArray[0][2], sortable:true}
                    ],
                    data = [
                        {Company:$rowArray[1][0], Phone:$rowArray[1][1], Contact:$rowArray[1][2]},
                        {Company:$rowArray[2][0], Phone:$rowArray[2][1], Contact:$rowArray[2][2]},
                        {Company:$rowArray[3][0], Phone:$rowArray[3][1], Contact:$rowArray[3][2]}
                    ],
                    table = new Y.DataTable({
                        columns: cols,
                        data   : data,
                        summary: "Contacts list",
                        caption: "Table with simple column sorting"
                    }).render(params.key2);
                    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a `DataTable` object, but your requirement is that the named `columns` property to the constructor must be dynamic, rather than static.  Right?

Just because most every YUI example shows the `columns` property to be an in-line array, doesn't mean that it must be done that way.  You can build it dynamically ...

```
YUI().use("datatable-sort", function(Y) {

            // Build the column definitions dynamically, based on the names in $rowArray[0].
            var cols = [];
            for (i=0; i<$rowArray[0].length; i++) {
                cols.push( { key:$rowArray[0][i], label:$rowArray[0][i], sortable:true } );
            }

            var data = [
                ...
```

As for the JSFiddle that you provided (*Thank You!*), there is a mix-up of references to Name/Age/CGPA and Company/Phone/Contact.  You need to straighten that out.  Even after that, the JSFiddle gets an exception, but I'm out of time.  You can use your browser's built-in debugger to catch the exception and debug it.